# Textarea placeholder text not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an electron app and I'm having trouble with placeholder texts. I'm storing the HTML code in a variable and insert it in a `<div>` using jQuery.
This is my current implementation:

```
commentsHTML += '<textarea id="comment-new-textarea" rows="10" cols="1" placeholder="Placeholder Text Goes Here"></textarea>';
```

In other questions some people suggested this might be due to a space between the textarea tags. This doesn't seem to solve the issue, though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Its working: Try this: `var commentsHTML = '<textarea id="comment-new-textarea" rows="10" cols="1" placeholder="Placeholder Text Goes Here"></textarea>';
$('body').append(commentsHTML);`

Comment: Please add your whole code describing how and where are putting this `commentsHTML`

Comment: Do not have space between **<textarea></textarea>** opening and closing tags, otherwise you'll have empty spaces which you would have to delete everytime to see the placeholder.

Comment: id's should be unique in your document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have to check is :
just double-check that your DOCTYPE is correct for HTML5

And the second thing in my mind is :

I think its issue with the placeholder color so its not showing.

Here is example :

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me. I had the placeholder color set as white earlier on in another CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working fine at my sandbox.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var commentsHTML = '<textarea id="comment-new-textarea" rows="10" cols="250" placeholder="Placeholder Text Goes Here"></textarea>';
</script>
```

[image: here is browser support for place holder. Older version doesn't support.]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp

```js
var commentsHTML = '<textarea id="comment-new-textarea" rows="10" cols="250" placeholder="Placeholder Text Goes Here"></textarea>';
 $('div').html(commentsHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  </div>
```